# Please help me clarify some concepts with Java IO and maybe fall in love with it!

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the different types of stream IOs Java has to offer, so I wrote this little piece of code here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "English is being IOed!\nLine 2 has a number.\n中文字體(Chinese)";

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ByteIO.txt");
    Scanner fis = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("ByteIO.txt"));
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("CharIO.txt");
    Scanner fr = new Scanner(new FileReader("CharIO.txt"));

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("BufferedByteIO.txt"));
    Scanner bis = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("BufferedByteIO.txt")));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("BufferedCharIO.txt"));
    Scanner br = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BufferedCharIO.txt")));

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream((new FileOutputStream("DataBufferedByteIO.txt"))));
    Scanner dis = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream((new FileInputStream("DataBufferedByteIO.txt")))));

    try {
        System.out.printf("ByteIO:\n");
        fos.write(str.getBytes());
        while (fis.hasNext())
            System.out.print(fis.next());// in the form of a String

        System.out.printf("\nCharIO:\n");
        fw.write(str);
        while (fr.hasNext())
            System.out.print(fr.next());

        System.out.printf("\nBufferedByteIO:\n");
        bos.write(str.getBytes());
        bos.flush();// buffer is not full, so you'll need to flush it
        while (bis.hasNext())
            System.out.print(bis.next());

        System.out.printf("\nBufferedCharIO:\n");
        bw.write(str);
        bw.flush();// buffer is not full, so you'll need to flush it
        while (br.hasNext())
            System.out.print(br.next());

        System.out.printf("\nDataBufferedByteIO:\n");
        dos.write(str.getBytes());
        //dos.flush();// dos doesn't seem to need this...
        while (dis.hasNext())
            System.out.print(dis.next());
    } finally {
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
        fw.close();
        fr.close();
        bos.close();
        br.close();
        dos.close();
        dis.close();
    }

}
```

All it does is just write a pre-defined string into the file and then read it. The problem arises when I run the code, I get this:

```
ByteIO:
EnglishisbeingIOed!Line2hasanumber.中文字體(Chinese)
CharIO:
                        //<--Empty line here
BufferedByteIO:
EnglishisbeingIOed!Line2hasanumber.中文字體(Chinese)
BufferedCharIO:
EnglishisbeingIOed!Line2hasanumber.中文字體(Chinese)
DataBufferedByteIO:
                        //<--Empty line here
```

1. The files are all populated with the correct data, so I suppose something is wrong with the scanner, but I just don't know what went wrong, and I hope somebody can point the mistake out for me.
2. The files are all populated with the **same** data. That's weird, according to [Java I/O Streams](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/index.html), Byte Streams can only process single bytes, and only Character Streams can process Unicode, so shouldn't Byte Streams spit out gibberish when processing Chinese characters, which are UTF-16 (I think)? What exactly is the difference between a Byte Stream and a Character Stream (fos vs fw)?
3. On a partially unrelated topic, I thought Byte Streams were used to work with binary data such as music and images, I also thought that the data Byte Streams spit out should be illegible, but I seem to be wrong, am I? Exactly which [I/O Stream Class(es)](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/WritingIOSC/index.html) should I work with if I'm dealing with binary data?

Comment: Chinese characters aren't "UTF-16" nor "UTF-8" nor "UTF-32" nor ... well, UTF-anything.  Chinese characters are Unicode code points (in this context).  The various UTF encodings are just a way of assigning various bit patterns to the Unicode code points.  *ANY* language can be UTF-16-encoded.  Or UTF-8-encoded.  Or UTF-32-encoded.  Or UTF-7-encoded for that matter.

Comment: Ty! But Chinese characters aren't single bytes, right? So shouldn't they be incompatible with Byte Streams?

Comment: All character streams for real IO like files and sockets are actually bytes underneath. You can encode chinese characters as bytes.

Comment: Sheldon: Everything can be a byte stream.  If I have a 32-bit value, I can read it 8 bits at a time through a byte stream.  Again, it's all a matter of conventions in coding, not some hard, fixed definitions that are universal.

Comment: Thank you all!! I was extremely confused because I found this paragraph `Prior to JDK 1.1, the input and output classes (mostly found in the java.io package) only supported 8-bit byte streams. The concept of 16-bit Unicode character streams was introduced in JDK 1.1.` in the Java I/O Streams doc. The `16-bit Unicode character` in the doc made me think that this Unicode character must be something special, when it actually is simply 2 bytes stuck together by a special encoding rule. I hope I'm finally correct this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important concept to understand here is that of encoding.

`String`/`char[]`/`Writer`/`Reader` are used to deal with textual data of any kind.

`byte[]`/`OutputStream`/`InputStream` are used to deal with binary data. Also, a file on your disk only every stores binary data (yes, that's true, it will hopefully be a bit more clear in a minute).

Whenever you convert between those two worlds some kind of encoding will be in play. In Java, there are several ways to convert between those worlds *without specifying* an encoding. In this case, the platform default encoding will be used (which one this is depends on your platform and configuration/locale). [*]

The task of an encoding is to convert some given binary data (usually from a `byte[]`/`ByteBuffer`/`InputStream`) to textual data (usually into `char[]`/`CharBuffer`/`Writer`) *or the other way around*.

How *exactly* this happens depends on the encoding used. Some encodings (such as the ISO-8859-* family) are a simple mapping from `byte` values to corresponding unicode codepoints, others (such as UTF-8) are more complex and a single unicode codepoint can be anything from 1 to 4 bytes.

There's a quite nice article that gives a basic overview over the whole encoding issue titled: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

[*] Using the platform default encoding is usually not desired, because it makes your program un-portable and hard to use, but that's beside the point for this post.

Comment: So what you're saying is... All the data in the files are the same because there is some sort of encoding from textual data to binary data that a `Writer`/`Reader` does for me automatically? Which would also imply that there is also some sort of encoding from binary data to textual data when I open the files with the text editor.

Comment: @Sheldon: that's right. When you open a file in a text editor, then it will have to do some conversion as well. Usually this conversion happens automatically, which can go in two ways: the editor might *always* use the default encoding in the platform (which works just fine as long as it opens only files that are written using the same encoding) or it might try to auto-detect the encoding (which may work with some encodings and some files, but is a tricky problem that can go wrong easily).

Answer (score 2):

Using BufferedInputStream and DataInputStream does not alter the content of the data.

Byte stream is for reading binary data. It is not suitable here.

Character stream is for reading text, the scanner assumes you are reading new line terminated lines. (Which you don't appear to have)

If I run

```
String str = "English is being IOed!\nLine 2 has a number.\n\u4E2D\u6587\u5b57\u9ad4(Chinese)\n";
Writer fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("ReaderWriter.txt"), "UTF-8");
fw.write(str);
fw.close();
Reader fr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("ReaderWriter.txt"), "UTF-8");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fr);
String next = "";
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    next = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(next);
}
for (int i = 0; i < next.length(); i++)
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((int) next.charAt(i)));
fr.close();
```

I get

```
English
is
being
IOed!
Line
2
has
a
number.
????(Chinese)
4e2d
6587
5b57
9ad4
28
43
68
69
6e
65
73
65
29
```

You can see that the original characters are preserved. The '?' means the character could not be displayed on my terminal or my character encoding. (I don't know why)

Comment: 1.What do you mean by "alter the content of the data"? Alter it how? Isn't everything saved into binary, and read from binary?

Comment: My point is that what you read will be the same whether they are there or not.  I wanted to make it clear they have no impact on your test.

Comment: Ty! As for Line 3, `the scanner assumes you are reading new line terminated lines`. But I do have 2 \n terminated lines, aren't these new-line terminated lines? Why is my scanner neglecting them?

Comment: I don't see any `\n` at the end of `str`

Comment: I have a question: According to JavaDoc, a Scanner uses a delimitor to tokenize the string and cut it into little pieces. If the delimitor is not set, the default delimitor `' '` is used. Are you implying that Scanners use different delimitors when dealing with character streams?

Comment: @Sheldon, AFAIK the problem has nothing to do with the Scanner. Its much mroe likely there is a problem displaying Chinese characters. (At least this is what I found, see my edit)

Comment: Then it must be some sort of special usage for FileReader & DataInputStream which I haven't figured out/read about yet. Thanks for all your time Peter, I think really need to do alot more reading on Java IO Classes. There's just so many of them...

Comment: @Sheldon, why don't you start with the example I gave you. ;)  Remember Reader/Writer is for text and Streams are for binary data.  I used this approach so I could set the encoding used.  The default windows encoding corrupted the chinese characters.